# In Python, How do I make my input validation keep on looping if the user enters an incorrect value

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I make my code loop back to the input (and checking the values again) if the user inputted a number that is below 0 or higher than 100 or not entering a integer

```
NameList = []
Name1List = []
def Va():
    while True:
        try:
            int(NameMSplit[1])
            if int(NameMSplit[1]) > 0 and int(NameMSplit[1]) < 100:
                return NameMSplit[1]
            else:
                print ("Number is not between 0 and 100")
        except ValueError:
             print("Please make sure it's a number ")

#Main Code
NameMarks = input("Please input your name followed by your marks seperated by spaces ")
NameMSplit = NameMarks.split()
V = Va()
while NameMarks != 'Q':
    Name =(NameMSplit[0])
    Name1 = (NameMSplit[1])
    NameList.append(Name)
    Name1List.append(Name1)
    NameMarks = input("Please input your name followed by your marks seperated by spaces ")
    NameMSplit = NameMarks.split()
print (Name1List, NameList)
```

Comment: What is wrong with your current approach

Comment: If i input something like "g w" it will say "Please make sure it's a number" over and over again and not allowing me to start over again at the input, same goes with a input like "g 101"

Answer (score 0):

You can include the input in your function as follows:

```
def Va():
    while True:
        NameMarks = input("Please input your name followed by your marks seperated by spaces ")
        NameMSplit = NameMarks.split()
        try:
            int(NameMSplit[1])
            if int(NameMSplit[1]) > 0 and int(NameMSplit[1]) < 100:
                return NameMarks
            else:
                print ("Number is not between 0 and 100")
        except ValueError:
             print("Please make sure it's a number ")

#Main Code
NameMarks = Va()
...
```

Comment: @user3459426, In your main code, change `V = Va()` to `NameMarks = Va()` and in your function return `NameMarks` instead of returning `NameMSplit[1]`

Comment: Thanks for your help so far, I have encountered an error in my main code in which that if I enter  'Q' as my input to print my list i get an index error "List index out of range". I have also changed the last two lines of my main code to "NameMarks = Va()"